# Create List of Elements Added Through Dynamic Polling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I have a jQuery function that dynamically polls a Django view of mine every 10 seconds to see if new data has been added:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get('pollNewEntries', {}, newEntrySuccess)
}, 10000);

function newEntrySuccess(result) {
    $.each(result, function(index, value) {
        var dateString = new Date(value.fields.pubDate);
        dateString = dateString.toDateString() + " - " + dateString.toTimeString();
        var title = "<h1>" + value.fields.title + "</h1>";
        var authorAndDate = "<h4>" + value.fields.author + 
            " - <time datetime='>" + value.fields.pubDate + "'>" + dateString + 
            "</time>" + "</h4>";
        var text = "<div class='cutText'>" + value.fields.text; + "</div>";
        var html = "<article class='text'>" + title + authorAndDate + text + "</article>";
        $('#mainLeft').prepend(html);
    }); 
}
```

});

This works, but I've conservatively structured the polling interval and the view to account for any lag time, so the view will often return the same article as "new" for two or more separate Ajax calls.

What I want to do is save the id of any previously encountered new articles to some kind of set. Then I can query against that set every time the Ajax call returns a result, ensure that the article hasn't been encountered before, and only proceed if it's new.

I could set up a simple global list (or a customized set/dictionary, though the amount of articles is likely to be small so there won't be much of a difference in performance) to do this or I could do it with cookies, but I think the cookie overhead is a little overkill for this application and I know anything global is particularly toxic in javascript. Any other suggestions, or is going global the best option in this case?

Comment: Have you considered passing a index to "pollNewEntries" and let the server determine if there new content or not. Pass the last index of the processed article. A simple check would occur in the server preventing area of big global variables.

Comment: Why don't you change the code of `pollNewEntries` so it only returns the new articles instead of implementing a workaround on the client side?

Comment: Does each client browser have it's own set of articles to be displayed (such that you need to keep track on the server side) or are they a common set of articles for all clients (such that you can keep track of last time articles were request on client)?

Comment: Using Interval is a bad idea. You can end up with requests piling up on top of each other. Use setTimeout. Set a new timeout every time a request comes back.

Comment: The problem with doing it by id is this: what if a few articles are deleted, bringing the id on the server lower than the one previously seen on the client? Then I pass in the last seen id on the client, I see there are none higher than that on the server, and I do nothing, even though there may be a new article.

Comment: You could also use the timestamp from the last request for determining any updates.